# How to force a browser to reload angular template file and not cache it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-templates

When loading a javascript file I can force the browser to not use the cache by adding a version when loading the file e.g.

```
<script src="~/angular/myapp/app.js?version=123"></script>
```

From inside my angular app I am doing this:

```
$routeProvider.when("/", {
  controller: "userController",
  controllerAs: "vm",
  templateUrl: "Path/to/Template/Index.html"
});
```

How can I make sure that any changes I made to the `Index.html` won't be cached?  Or this isn't an issue for some reason?

angular 1.x

Comment: Is this an AngularJS (v1) or an Angular (v2+) question?

Comment: @BeetleJuice 1.x

Comment: If it's for development, then you can **disable cache** under Network tab in your browser console (*Chrome*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the same for your `Index.html` file. Simply append a "cache buster" query string as you did to your js file. There are a few techniques to do this, but a simple `Date.now()` timestamp should demonstrate the goal
...

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
  controller: 'userController',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  templateUrl: `Path/to/Template/Index.html?t=${Date.now()}`
});
```

If your app grows in complexity and you wish to prevent caching of templates altogether, you can achieve this with some middleware...

```
angular.module('preventTemplateCache').factory('preventTemplateCache', function($injector) {
  return {
    'request': function(config) {
      if (config.url.indexOf('views') !== -1) {
        config.url = `${config.url}?t=${Date.now()}`
      }
      return config;
    }
  }
}).config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('preventTemplateCache');
});
```

The above example assumes a directory of `views` for your templates.

---

Finally, as a comment pointed out, if you are simply wishing to prevent caching for local development, you can toggle settings to disable cached resources through your browsers dev tools.

Comment: Okay, well that was the third small point of my answer. Everything above it should be applicable. Please let me know if helpful

Comment: @coolbreeze in other words, I don't understand your comment as it pertains to a very small point of my answer. Did you try the techniques above it?

Comment: I was just responding to your "if you are simply wishing to prevent caching for local development". thanks!

Comment: I still don't understand, does my answer work for you? Please accept (green check) if it does so we can both get a little rep and let other users who see this know this was a solution. Thanks!